# Deleting answers due to the Homework policy is not beneficial

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, homework-and-exercises

The homework policy doesn't seems like a counter-productive policy on Stack Exchange.

I understand Stack Exchange policing their questions, but policing removing answers to "homework like questions" seems counter productive, especially once answers.

Take this question for example:
[How much room do you need to safely exit terminal velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601359/)

I'm a middle-aged person, and I just take a general interest into physics.
I posted a question which perhaps could have been a bit more specific, in what I've attempted to resolve the problem.

However, I know very little in the field of physics.
My question was graciously answered and accepted before the question was closed.
Yet the answer was removed due to the homework policy.

1. A user took their time to accurately answer my question, so why are we going to penalize them?
2. I'm not in school for this, and even if I were to be, the question accurately described the steps to achieve the goal and would be beneficial to the entire community
3. The homework policy is ambiguous. What determines a "homework like question"?
4. The homework policy only punishes new users, because anyone with enough rep will be able to see deleted answers and its would be wrong to assume that people with 15k cannot be students.

This policy seems outdated, and harmful to the community.

I can understand closing a question based off of policy, but what benefit do we get from deleting answers?

Furthermore, can you give me a clear concise definition of a homework style question? Or is a homework style question really just a loose term which can be used to close and remove questions based off of individual bias?

Comment: As per the [Homework Policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/170832) and the reason for closing it could have been that it "didn't show enough research prior to asking" or it [needs details or clarity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) - I'd guess (on behalf of the closers) that it was ~80%/20% those reasons. --- It is possible to edit and improve the question, then ask for it to be reopened; assuming that it wouldn't invalidate the answer that too could be undeleted - it's generally the case that off-topic questions shouldn't be answered.

Comment: as to the last bit: see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10938/36194

Answer (score 12):

With due respect: we've already had this debate *ad nauseum*.  Check [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/36194) from 2014 as a representative example, or more recent posts [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10555/36194) , or [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9710/36194).  PSE is NOT a homework site.

Whether or not this is a homework question *to you* is not this issue: if it is not then you have posted your question on the wrong site.  The community took the decision to avoid the inevitable deluge that would follow if we allowed homework questions.

You claim it is not a homework question: fine.  But there is no way for people to know this, and moreover it could be a homework question *for someone else*.

Speaking for myself as a professional instructor:

1. There is already massive plagiarism on various sites on the part of some students.  The objective of assignments is not to hunt for others to provide answers.
2. Given the current exceptional circumstances where many students now take online exams, I am grateful that PSE is particularly vigilant in promptly identifying and closing possible exam questions; those would resemble homework questions.

It is possible to get away with "homework-style" questions if they are constructed as questions on a specific concept: see [this discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10938/36194) for instance.

Comment: The fact that the debate have been going on ad nauseam is probably due to the fact that the homework policy is considered unsatisfactory by many. Personally, I think it's one of the most convoluted and wrong policies I've ever seen, and frequently applied blindly. It's actually a policy which keeps me at distance from this site. I'd be happy to see it nuked.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano For what it's worth, I'd also like to see it nuked and replaced with something better -- but the community hasn't been able to come up with an agreeable solution that is better. I think we're all open to suggestions, but letting all homework questions in won't fly.

Comment: Can you give me a clear consise definition of Homework style question? Or is homework style question really just a loose term which can be used to close and remove questions based off of individual bias?

Comment: @johnny5 I would define a homework style question is one where the value of the answer is primarily in learning the process of solving it, not in the specific answer. In your case, deciding how to slow down to not break a bone either is only valuable in learning how to solve kinematic problems (which is physics, but is homework) or it's engineering and off topic (I need to design a system for skydivers).

Comment: That's what you would define it as. But the guidelines don't provide a clear understanding of what a homework style question. If you're going for your masters some of the valid questions or specific questions could be considered the same.

Comment: Additionally I have no problem with closing the question before hand but why delete the answer?

Comment: @johnny5 As I stated in my answer -- we delete full answers temporarily for questions that appear to be homework-like. This is to prevent potential academic dishonesty. The answer can be undeleted at a future date when it is much less likely that it could be used to cheat on an assignment.

Comment: @johnny5 And the definition I gave for homework-like is [the first sentence of the homework policy post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/6634) (not counting the summary section). Is there something about that which could be improved to clear up any confusions?

Comment: @johnny5 Given it takes 5 votes to close a question it's certainly not a *personal* bias; very few users have the instant power to close a homework question.    See the last link of my post for some guidance on concocting conceptual questions.  There is an element of "vagueness", and some questions get through but by-and-large the policy works, and occasional excesses are remedied through meta when users plead their case.

Comment: This policy is only biased to new users who don't have the knowledge to explain there question more accurately.  1.  Anyone with enough points will be able to view the answer.  Implying that it's okay to cheat if youre part of the community.  2. The answer that was deleted provided a clear explaintion which helped the learning process.  3.  Alot of questions asked by people with more experience can easily be closed for the same reason but this policy is mostly applied to new users.

Comment: For the most part I'm just requesting that questions which are already answered not to be deleted, or if we can make an exception for this particular one. I'm not a student.  I'm a software engineer with general curiosity.

Comment: @johnny5 I can appreciate that motivation -- part of what we struggle with is how to know when somebody is a student and when somebody isn't. People can be, or can say they are, anything and we can't verify it. We've had people post questions *from their classroom in the middle of exams* before, but we couldn't tell until they left a comment saying so. If there's a way to distinguish legitimate copied-from-an-assignment questions and ones that just look like they could have been, that'd be really helpful!

Comment: @johnny5 Your comments are off the mark here.  There are about 150 users who earned the privilege to access to deleted posts, out of 215k+ total users, and I doubt very much if these users care very about answers to homework questions.  I am not denying the deleted answer was useful, but pointing out it was deleted because it provided a complete solution to a homework problem.  Finally, I do not think people with significant “experience” ask this type of question.  Surely there are exceptions to each of the above...

Comment: ... but the experienced users are experienced precisely because the format of the site - which *excludes* homework questions - was to their liking.   There are plenty of site that attract people *interested* in homework-type of question.

Comment: @tpg2114 why is it stackexchanges responsibility to make assumptions about how the data is going to be used.    We have no problem with this information being used to develop weapons, but cheating in schools is where we draw the line? The stance on homework is hypocritical

Comment: I know I won't be able to change the opinion of the community from this post espicially since it cannot gain enough traction.  But this policy is not fair nor uniform to the community.   The reasons for deleting answers based on the assumption on how they're going to be used is rediculous

Comment: @johnny5 I understand not liking the policy, but I don't understand calling it ridiculous. Certainly you can at least understand the point of it and why someone would want to have it in place? If you're not willing to at least try and understand the other side and just dismiss it entirely then what's the point of a conversation? There are other online sites for homework help; PSE is just not one of those sites.

Comment: The policy is *absolutely ridiculous*, and violates the fundamental tenets of the Stack Exchange Q&A model. That you have decided to create such a policy is shameful, and that you are defending it with no sense of irony is just embarrassing for both you and the site. The discussion has *indeed* been had *ad nauseam*, on Meta Stack Exchange. You've badly misinterpreted the conclusion of those discussions.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I understand what the policy is trying to do.  But its ridiculous for the following reason.  1. Its takes a stance on what questions can be used for. e.g Its okay if your making bombs for work, but if you try to cheat thats a no-no.  2.  It discrimates against new users who don't have the knowledge to rephrase their question.  3.  If you have enough point's you're able to view deleted answers, (which on othersite such as SO, its easy to achieve, so people who have those points are allowed to ask questions like that

Comment: @CodyGray As far as I'm aware, any "debate" on the main stack exchange site is pretty irrelevant to this discussion.  Sites are able to define their own scopes with community input, and every time it is brought up, the majority consensus here is to not allow homework-like questions.  What other network sites choose to do is up to them, but the policy actually has a lot of support on Physics SE from active members.  I would also love to hear what specific "fundamental tenets" of SE would require us to act as a homework solving site.

Comment: The whole point of the Stack Exchange network is a cohesive network of Q&A sites. So, yes, the network-wide policies apply to all sites, including this one. Obviously there is no requirement that anyone act as a homework solving site. That's a straw man argument. The question in question wasn't homework, was clearly about physics, was of sufficiently narrow definition to be answered in a Q&A format, and didn't ask for opinions. Furthermore, there is a very real issue of a legitimate answer to that question being deleted, with no justification whatsoever. That's also a network policy violation.

Comment: @CodyGray You're going to need to cite specific policies if you're going to claim that it is a "network policy violation".  Sites _are_ able to determine their own scope, and this community has decided many times that providing the solution to exercise problems is outside of our scope.  Like every site, just because the question has to do with physics, it does not make it inherently on-topic, and each site explains this in the "What questions can I ask about here?" help section.

Comment: Yes, I read the Help Center. Nowhere there do I see anything that the question in question violates. Deleting legitimate attempts to answer the question is inappropriate. There is hardly going to be a reference that I can cite for the obvious. Although there is [this pretty clear policy about when answers should be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), at least in response to "not an answer" flags.

Comment: @CodyGray That's about when things should be deleted as "Not an answer" from what I can tell, that is not giving a complete rundown of the only reason an answer can be deleted.  There's also [this main meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322333/who-decides-on-a-sites-content-policy) which as-is suggests that it is completely okay for us to have our homework policy.

Answer (score 11):

To answer the specific question about the benefit of deleting answers to homework questions, I'll cite [the homework policy itself](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange):

> ### Why don't you provide a complete answer to homework questions?
>
> This is pretty well covered by a [discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415) on the Math Stack Exchange site.
>
> > Providing an answer that doesn't help
> > a student learn is not in the
> > student's own best interest, and if a
> > solution complete enough to be copied
> > verbatim and handed in is given
> > immediately, it will encourage more
> > people to use the site as a free
> > homework service. In the spirit of
> > creating a lasting resource of
> > mathematical knowledge, you may come
> > back after a suitable amount of time
> > and edit your response to include a
> > more complete answer. Or even better,
> > the student can post his own correct
> > answer!
>
> If someone posts an answer to a homework-type question that gives away a complete or near-complete solution, in most cases it will be temporarily deleted.

So that means if somebody posts a complete or near complete answer, we will delete it *temporarily*. If the question is on-topic and the person who posted the answer pings us some time later, we will often undelete the answer once the danger of academic dishonesty passes.

---

But of course, there's a lot of background on how we got to this policy.

The policies on our site (and really all Stack Exchange sites) are designed to strike a balance between many different needs and desires of users. For almost all sites, there are two core tenants that underlie everything:

1. The sites are a place to connect to and learn from professionals in the topic area.
2. Posts (questions and answers) are designed to help *every* future reader, and not just the person asking the question.

Our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange), or perhaps more precisely, our policy on "homework and homework-like questions", tries to thread a complicated needle while upholding those core tenants.

Through many long discussions within the community, the consensus opinion was that allowing homework questions deters professional participation in the site. People who are researchers or professors or engineers, by and large, don't enjoy answering the same types of questions on Newtonian mechanics where the answer is always "draw a freebody diagram." I understand that for new users to the site or people new to physics see that as a really interesting and fascinating area, but for people who have worked in the area forever, it's not that interesting and it drowns out the interesting questions if we allowed them repeatedly where the only variation on the question is specific values involved.

We also want to help every future reader of the site, which means questions should be general and conceptual, rather than focused on how to complete a particular calculation. In your particular example, the question is looking for a specific calculation and that's why it was closed.

If you had asked "How would one set up a kinematic problem like..." then it becomes conceptual. Rather than "Here's the distance" as an answer, a good answer becomes a recipe that will be true for solving *all* kinematic problems that are similar. And that's really helpful, because we can point all future users with similar questions to that core conceptual Q&A.

Comment: The current policy, is only is baised towards new users, who don't have enough knowledge to rephrase a question.

Comment: Additionaly the term homework style question is subjective, and any question could be considered homework style through various levels of education

Comment: The policy is fundamentally wrong and misguided. It focuses on all the wrong things. The network-wide policy is simple: **the origin or genesis of a question doesn't matter**. We don't care if it's homework or not. It only matters if the question itself fits into the Q&A format. If it does, great; if not, close. These are not a drain on professionals, because they can be answered once and future questions closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray PSE's homework policy doesn't care about the origin either. We call it "homework-like" in the close banner; we really don't care if it was actually assigned as homework or not though. Please take the time to learn more about the policy before criticizing it.

Comment: It's still a terrible policy, @BioPhysicist, in direct contrast with everything that the Stack Exchange network stands for. It's even worse if you decide that you are the gatekeepers of who "deserves" an answer. The existence of the [homework] tag, in particular, is an abomination. Stack Exchange explicitly discourages the use of such "meta" tags. And the naming of that tag stands in stark contrast to your last message, given that it *labels* the question as "homework".

Comment: @CodyGray The tag isn't "homework", so the tag does allow for questions that were not assigned as homework.

Comment: The tag is "homework-or-exercise", which isn't any better. What is an "exercise"? Something that you, in your infinite wisdom, deem to be too close to homework? That's a slippery slope and entirely non-objective. You are not the arbiter of who deserves an answer. No "homework" policy is needed. Just evaluate the question as asked.

Comment: @CodyGray The tag description gives the "definition", and it even says it doesn't have to be explicitly assigned as homework. "*Applies to questions of primarily educational value - not only questions that arise from actual homework assignments, but any question where it is preferable to guide the asker to the answer rather than giving it away outright.*" I understand coming from a negative space, but a positive is that just handing out exercise solutions isn't always the best way to teach someone. I prefer the site's focus on concepts over worked solutions.

Comment: Focusing on concepts is great. That has nothing to do with *deleting legitimate answers*, though. This idea of "guiding" people is antithetical to a Q&A site. It isn't about the asker. They don't matter at all. It's about the countless numbers of people who will find the question using a web search. This, like all Stack Exchange sites, is *not* a help desk. This policy you laud so much is, ironically, having the opposite effect: trying to turn the site into a homework help service, instead of a Q&A site. If you're dealing in "hints", rather than *answers*, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree; hints are not useful and should be removed. We prefer full answers here.

Comment: @CodyGray We do evaluate the question on its merits, and just because it has a homework tag doesn't mean it gets closed or is off topic. Asking for a specific calculation, as was done here, is the equivalent of "How do I write code to do X" that you get on SO. The merits we judge the question on are quite clear -- it's what's in the policy, what's on the sidebar -- questions need to ask about the **concept** and not for a **calculation**. Call it something different, but the question would still be closed on its merits because it is asking for a calculation and not concepts.

Comment: "How do I write code to do X" is perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow. As should be questions on Physics about how to calculate a particular quantity.

Comment: And the need to do that *is* to help future users find something, because "Please calculate this" is not searchable, it's not findable, and when we close people's questions as duplicates, we get into protracted arguments with said user about how their question is the same even though it's asking about trains and not falling spheres. For all its flaws, the policy we have is one decided by the community, again and again, through years and multiple discussions -- it is the epitome of community/site-governance. Calling it completely antithetical to the way SE works is a bit extreme.

Comment: @CodyGray But it requires more than "My inputs are Y and I'd like to do X" -- you need minimal working examples, you need some evidence that you aren't just asking somebody else to do your job. We need the same thing here for "homework" to be on-topic. We need to see what work was done so far, we need to see where you got stuck (the error log, so to speak).

Comment: A minimal working example and error logs are only required on Stack Overflow if you're asking others to debug your code. Just like the full calculations would be required if you were asking here what was wrong with your calculations. That's very different from asking "how do I do x?". All questions on Stack Exchange are asking for others to do some work for them. That's the whole nature of a Q&A site: ask questions, get answers from someone else. It's very important to understand this point and stop thinking that your job is to function as the gatekeeper of who deserves an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray There's a wide difference between questions getting answers by others, and literally getting others to do your work for you.  The latter is something that this community, through extended discussions, has decided it wants to avoid.  A lot of this motivation actually comes from users who also teach, and have concerns that this site would be used to circumvent actually doing questions.  Understandably, a teacher may not feel comfortable on a site that just answers homework, but they may be comfortable on a site discussing the topics.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not really sure how you're making the leap from our policy to us deciding *who* deserves an answer. It's pretty clear to me that we're deciding which *questions* deserve an answer, without regard to the person who posted it. Doesn't matter if the person is a student or not, is a professional or not, has a million rep or not -- we don't answer "Please calculate this for me" unless it asks about concepts. I'm not sure where the status of the asker comes in at all.

Comment: Your scope is such that you would not answer basic questions about performing calculations in physics? This is *fundamentally broken*. No, it isn't about users. It's about defining your site's scope in such an arbitrary manner that it excludes legitimate, practical, useful questions about physics. I cannot understand this. I cannot understand the rationale for this. It was my understanding that this was a Stack Exchange site, with certain fundamental principles at play. Based on what I'm being told here, you've decided to do things completely differently, and I find that very distressing.

Comment: @CodyGray I think part of the challenge for folks is that when people take a "physics" class, it's all essentially one topic -- Newtonian mechanics. And they think "physics" is just plugging things into a couple of equations and balancing forces. For most professional physicists, Newtonian mechanics is something they took in high school and never used again. I'm struggling for analogies, but it would be kinda like someone thinking that programming is really just typing, so they come to SO to ask how to type faster or something. If we have a *professional* or *expert* level, then the...

Comment: kinds of questions that get closed as "homework" wouldn't even register as something professionals or experts see or do as "physics" really. If we allow it, because 90% of the world thinks that's what defines physics, the site would be almost nothing but questions that only non-experts find useful or interesting or engaging. And our community decided to strike a balance -- experts will teach concepts, but not run calculations. Students can ask concepts, but not for calculations.

Comment: And our site grew out of the merger of a few sites, one of which was "Theoretical Physics" and that subset of the community wanted to keep things at an even higher level than we allow now. The policy is an act of compromise, and like most acts of compromise, nobody loves it. But it's kept the site operating and growing for years.

Comment: I see. So you are for "experts" only, covering only advanced topics of interest to them? Stack Overflow doesn't have this policy. We allow questions from both beginning and expert programmers. Yes, experts no longer have trouble getting "hello, world" to compile, and find such questions boring, but beginners do, and so we allow them in the interest of serving the larger good and providing a definitive reference for the long tail of programming-related questions. Unless, of course, they are duplicates, then we close them, because nobody likes saying the same thing over and over.

Comment: You say that you don't care about people, but you keep making a distinction between experts and students. So... that's kinda contradictory. Especially since you have no way of knowing who is or isn't a student.

Comment: @CodyGray We do answer "hello world" type questions when people have trouble getting it to compile. We just don't do it when they drop in and say "How do I program 'hello world'." And we don't like saying the same things over and over again either, and the repetitive calculations are things the community stressed they don't want to do.

Comment: And no, we're not for experts only. But you have to have experts around in order to answer questions, otherwise nothing gets done. If you drive all the people who know the answers away, then you get a ghost of a site with no content and no community. So, we have to strike the balance between what kinds of questions people want to ask, and what kinds of questions people are willing to donate their time to answer. If we don't strike that balance, we don't have a community or a site.

Comment: If people want to learn the *concepts* underlying how to tackle physics problems, we're their site. If they want a place to do calculations for them, there's plenty of other places on the internet that do that. We want to be a center for high quality, definitive Q&A on how physics *works*, at all levels.

Comment: And... you do not see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/601359) as asking about a concept? I find this very puzzling. It definitely looks like a question about a concept to me. The only problem with it is, as you mentioned earlier, it's about something "boring", namely Newtonian mechanics. Even *I* find that boring, to be honest, and I'm not a professional physicist. On the other hand, "boring" does not a question invalid make.

Comment: @CodyGray No, I don't -- it says "What is the distance." If it said "How do I set up the equations for the forces" or "What forces need to be accounted for" or a multitude of other possible concepts that could go towards solving the problem, then it wouldn't be off topic. It would take a relatively minor edit to bring it in line with the need for conceptual questions, and then it could be reopened (although there would need to be clarification on what speed or acceleration breaks bone). Or if it said "Here's my free-body-diagram and I get it takes infinite distance, but I don't know why."

Comment: And I get that sometimes people have no idea where to start and can't point to a concept that they are stuck on. When that happens, folks generally use comments to ask questions that prompt OP to explain where they are and where they are stuck, then ask those to be edited into the question if it's conceptual (and not something like hitting the wrong button on a calculator). Then the post can be reopened and the concepts addressed.

Comment: If you think the question can be easily reworded into something that would be suitable for this site, I am quite puzzled at why you have allowed the question to remain closed, rather than making those trivial edits. On Stack Overflow, there are sometimes questions that are asking how to solve a problem, but the asker unknowingly phrases it as seeking recommendations for an off-site resource. We don't allow recommendation questions because they often turn into race to the bottom for spam, but when they can be easily edited to meet our guidelines, we prefer to do that.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, because I can't read minds so I don't know which concept(s) gave trouble such that OP came here to ask, and also because I wasn't involved with the question until this meta post arrived last night. While the edits that are needed might be minor, we can't know *which* edits are of relevance or not. When it's clear what edits are needed, we generally do make them (and try to before the post gets closed).

Comment: Hmm, that's a real shame. This has been very enlightening. I would have previously been quick to praise and recommend this site, based on my respect for one of your former moderators and my assumptions about how it must work, based on my deep familiarity with the SE model. I no longer feel that way. I feel that this site's management diverges fundamentally from the SE model, in a way that is very much misguided and harmful. Furthermore, I see that the moderator team supports this, instead of working to resolve the problem. I cannot express in words how sad and disappointing this is to know.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, the site can't be perfect for everyone.  The current policies are based on community input, the same as every SE meta basically, so that they best reflect what the community wants.  Obviously not everyone wants the same things, but when the majority of feedback consistently says no homework-like questions, it makes a lot of sense to go with the majority.  I personally believe allowing those questions would be misguided and harmful.

Comment: @JMac, the policy is morality based BS.  No one has brought up a counter point to the fact that the SE allows questions about weapons and their creation etc. But we don't allow questions about homework.   Great to know where the communities morals stand

Comment: @johnny5 Well asking how to make a weapon here would almost definitely be off-topic as engineering, and I'm not sure if Engineering SE would explain how to make a weapon either.  Someone asking about _concepts_ that could be applied to make a weapon wouldn't be stopped, because we are talking about physics, not how to design a weapon.  In a similar vein with homework, you can't ask "what's the answer to this?" or "how do I solve this?" but you can ask about the related physics concepts in a way that can allow you to complete your homework yourself.

Comment: So you're saying it's okay to make assumptions about how some questions are asked, but not others.  We're fine with helping people who would use this in an industry for creating weapons, but when a student tries to ask a question at there level of general understanding, it's not okay to help them because they might use it to cheat.

Comment: @johnny5 No, the point is that we answer conceptual physics questions.  Physics is a pretty useful topic, and the concepts on-topic for this site could be used to answer physics homework easier than they could be used to build weapons IMO.  We don't provide solutions to homework problems though, the same as we don't tell someone how to build a weapon.  Both are entirely out of scope for the site.  We aren't trying to help people make weapons or prevent people from being able to do homework, we are just answering questions about physics concepts.

Comment: Hmm, making assumptions again about how the knowledge wlll be used and then dissmissing others based on probability... Pretty hypocritical

Comment: @johnny5 No, there are no assumptions. We answer conceptual physics questions. We don't provide solutions to homework problems. That's it. The thought process is not "let's try to infer the intent of this question, and then let's close it based on that inference." We really don't care about the intent of the question, where it comes from, who it comes from, etc. It's really just a scope classification independent of any the question's origin or intent.

Comment: @johnny5 What assumptions am I making?  _You're_ the one assuming that we are willing to help people make weapons but unwilling to help people complete homework.  No one else is saying this.  I said conceptual questions are on topic, whether you use that to answer homework or build a weapon is entirely outside the scope of this site.