# I don't know how to be on-topic

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755514/) question that got closed as off-topic and I don't know what makes it on-topic.

Clicking on one of the links takes me to a page that says "A homework question is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself." Then what I'm I missing?

Its is a regular physics problem on rolling yet the close comment says it's not useful to a broader audience  :( The comment also says asking  about specific computations makes the question off-topic but I was just showing my attempt (which I guess is necessary here).

Comment: Have you checked the related posts linked on the right panel?  See also [this link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10938/36194) or more recently [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14355/36194).

Comment: *The comment also says asking about specific computations makes the question off-topic but I was just showing my attempt (which I guess is necessary here).* The statement in the parenthesis does not follow from the preceding statement.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of issues with your last closed question which I'll explain.

- Homework-type question are essentially off-topic **unless** they are about explaining a concept.  Your post does not appear to involve any need to explain a concept, but you just ask "what to do next" - that's not a conceptual issue, that's just solving the problem for you, which is explicitly off-topic.
- The check-my-work rule also comes into play here as it seems you're asking us to check what you did in order to tell you what to do next.  Yes you show your work, but with no conceptual issue apparently involved.

To get the question answered you would need to make clear what conceptual issue you are having.

We simply do not provide worked out answers to questions like these, nor do we check arithmetic.  If we did half the planet would be posting homework problems here.

It is probably worth also saying that when teachers set homework problems it is to often to identify what problems students are having solving them, not simply to grade them.  It is actually useful to a teacher to know when a student is struggling and what they are struggling with.  The the teacher can address that in class or individually.  Having an internet website solve the problem for the student is interfering with the feedback a teacher needs to see what they need to teach.  This is not the reason for the homework policy, but it's an issue I think many members here would be aware of.

So the onus in on the poster to provide a conceptual issue that needs to be explained.